# Ubuntu 14.04 DHCP client not updating Windows DNS

Tags: 14.04, windows, dns, dhcp

We have a set of Windows 2012R2 domain controllers which provide DNS and DHCP service for the network.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server which is getting addresses via DHCP. This works correctly. In the Windows DHCP server, I have converted the lease to a reservation. In the DHCP server interface, I can see that the hostname of the client is properly being displayed, so I know the client is properly sending the hostname back.

However, the DNS servers do not seem to be able to resolve the address. Probing the DNS servers via dig returns no records for the hostname.

Windows DHCP clients in the domain which have reservations properly update DNS.

Any pointers on how to resolve this?

Comment: Are your DHCP servers set to update DNS even with an unauthenticated requests?  Have you ticked the dox in DNS properties on the server role that is listed as "Dynamically update DNS A and PTR records for DHCP client that do not request updated (for example, clients running Windows NT 4.0)?